# Python define function to subset datafram by a condition in a specific column

Tags: python, function, subset, finance

Trying to create a function to make new dataframes for each sector, but not sure what I am doing wrong in the return portion of the function.

This is what I have done to create the numbers for each sector. then in my data I have a column gsector that has the numbers in it for the corresponding sector. Hopefully this makes sense.

```
# Create a list of the GICS Sectors 
Energy = 10
Materials = 15 
Industrials = 20
Consumer_Discretionary = 25
Consumer_Staples = 30
Health_Care = 35
Financials = 40
Information_Technology = 45
Communication_Services = 50
Utilities = 55
Real_Estate = 60

GICS_Sectors = [Energy,Materials,Industrials,Consumer_Discretionary,Consumer_Staples,Health_Care,Financials,Information_Technology,Communication_Services,Utilities,Real_Estate]
##############################################################################

def Sector_Subset(dataframe,GICS_Sectors):
    """
    This function takes a dataframe and will pull sector specific data 
    to create a new dataframe for each eactor

    Parameters:
        dataframe = Portfolio
        GICS_Sectors = Each 11 sectors

    Return:
        GICS_dataframe

    Notes:
        We want to do this so we can easily graph momentum separately to compare sectors
    """
        dataframe[['datadate','GVKEY','trt1m','gsector','Start_Date','Rank_Percentile','Buy_Date','Sell_Date']]
return [dataframe.groupby('gsector').get_group(d) for d in GICS_Sectors]


Energy_Portfolio = Sector_Subset(Portfolio,Energy)
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do, and why do you think it's wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What I am trying to do is define the function so that it splits up the large dataframe Portfolio into 11 smaller dataframes according the the # that is in the gsector column which I have created a list for names GICS_Sectors
Once I have the function I want to create a loop to use the function to create those 11 dataframes

Answer (score 0):

The most likely error is in the last line of your example

Instead of:

```
return [dataframe.get_group(d) for d in GICS_Sectors]
```

You should write:

```
return [dataframe.groupby('gsector').get_group(d) for d in GICS_Sectors]
```

As you earlier mentioned, you want to group your data by 'gsector' column. However, it wasn't specified anywhere in the snipped. I'm not 100% it was your issue - variables Portfolio and Energy weren't declared, so I had to guess.

Here is my working example code with a random data in a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

# Modified original function
def Sector_Subset(dataframe,GICS_Sectors):
    """
    This function takes a dataframe and will pull sector specific data 
    to create a new dataframe for each eactor

    Parameters:
        dataframe = Portfolio
        GICS_Sectors = Each 11 sectors

    Return:
        GICS_dataframe

    Notes:
        We want to do this so we can easily graph momentum separately to compare sectors
    """

dataframe[['datadate','GVKEY','trt1m',
           'gsector','Start_Date','Rank_Percentile',
           'Buy_Date','Sell_Date']]

    # Below is the suspected error
    return [dataframe.groupby('gsector').get_group(d) for d in GICS_Sectors]
    # Original code
    # return [dataframe.get_group(d) for d in GICS_Sectors]

# Example data
Portfolio = {'datadate':['2020-03-20', '2020-03-19', '2020-03-18', '2020-03-17'],
        'GVKEY':[201, 211, 191, 181],
        'trt1m':[202, 212, 192, 182],
        'gsector':['Italy', 'Poland', 'Germany', 'Italy'],
        'Start_Date':['2020-03-15', '2020-02-19', '2020-03-13', '2020-03-11'],
        'End_Date':['2020-03-16', '2020-03-19', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-12'],
        'Rank_Percentile':['30th', '40th', '45th', '29th'],
        'Buy_Date':['2020-03-15', '2020-03-15', '2020-03-15', '2020-03-15'],
        'Sell_Date':['2020-03-17', '2020-03-18', '2020-03-165', '2020-03-15']}

# Test the function
Portfolio = pd.DataFrame(Portfolio)
Energy = ['Italy', 'Poland', 'Germany']
Energy_Portfolio = Sector_Subset(Portfolio, Energy)

# Print results
for enrg in Energy_Portfolio:
    print('\n')
    print(enrg)
```

Comment: so I reran that with the new line of code and get this error:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Please, edit your post and add the variables **Energy** and **Portfolio**. You don't have to show us the real data, but it's hard to find the bug without seeing the full picture. It seems as if you pass an int as **Energy** (for example 500) instead of list or any iterable variable.

Comment: I would try to call your function this way:
`Energy_Portfolio = Sector_Subset(Portfolio,[Energy])`
It seems that Energy in your code is a single integer variable - this way you will create a list with one element.
It can still give you an error 'KeyError: 500' if no row in column gsector has value from **Energy** (in my example it would be 500).

Comment: I just added how I defined each sector..will this still work then?

Comment: So that worked..but now what it does is it turns it into a list with a dataframe inside it...is there a way to make it go straight to a dataframe?

Comment: You could try using `pd.concat(Energy_Portfolio)`, but it would give you a table with headers written only once - you would be back to the square one, though your records with the same region would be near each other.